# Check if logged in - React Router - Redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Router where some Routes check if the user is logged in. The function calls the backend and returns either true or false. This part is working fine but when i call the function to either render the requested component or the redirect, it always renders the redirect.

```
function requireAuth() {
axiosInst.post("http://localhost:3001/checkLogged")
.then(function (response) { 
  if (response.data.user) {
    return true
  }else{
    return false
  }
})
}
```

```
    <Router>
      <>
        <Navigation/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login/" exact component={Login} ></Route>
          <Route path="/register/" exact component={Register} />
          <Route path="/" exact component={Feed} />
          <Route path="/articles/" exact component={Feed} />
          <Route path="/profile/" >
            {requireAuth() ? <Profile/> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/settings/" component={Settings} />
          <Route path="/write/" >
            {requireAuth() ? <Write/> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/search/" component={Search} />
          <Route path="/articles/:id" component={ArticleView} />
        </Switch>
      </>
    </Router>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `requireAuth` is async and when it returns the boolean, React already rendered the Redirect.

Why don't you use a state variable? Something like:

```
const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

... 

function requireAuth() {
axiosInst.post("http://localhost:3001/checkLogged")
.then(function (response) { 
  if (response.data.user) {
    setAuth(true);
    return true;
  }else{
    setAuth(false);
    return false;
  }
})
}

...

    <Router>
      <>
        <Navigation/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login/" exact component={Login} ></Route>
          <Route path="/register/" exact component={Register} />
          <Route path="/" exact component={Feed} />
          <Route path="/articles/" exact component={Feed} />
          <Route path="/profile/" >
            {auth ? <Profile/> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/settings/" component={Settings} />
          <Route path="/write/" >
            {auth ? <Write/> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/search/" component={Search} />
          <Route path="/articles/:id" component={ArticleView} />
        </Switch>
      </>
    </Router>
```

Comment: True. So then i don't have to wrap it in a function or just call the function immediately.
Thanks!!

Comment: Yes exactly. React render works with state variable so if you have to conditional render something you have to use `useState`

Answer (score -1):

You are making mistake inside requireAuth function. Inside this function then is returning true/false but requireAuth function is not returning anything. So to make requireAuth function return true/false you should return axios value to this function. And also axios returns promises, so to handle promises, it is suggested to use async function

```
async function requireAuth() {
   return await axiosInst.post("http://localhost:3001/checkLogged")
    .then(function (response) { 
      if (response.data.user) {
        return true
      }else{
        return false
      }
   })
}
```

And modify your route code to:

```
....
const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
requireAuth().then((res)=>{setAuth(res)})
return(
  <Router>
      <>
        <Navigation/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login/" exact component={Login} ></Route>
          <Route path="/register/" exact component={Register} />
          <Route path="/" exact component={Feed} />
          <Route path="/articles/" exact component={Feed} />
          <Route path="/profile/" >
            {auth ? <Profile/> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/settings/" component={Settings} />
          <Route path="/write/" >
            {auth ? <Write/> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/search/" component={Search} />
          <Route path="/articles/:id" component={ArticleView} />
        </Switch>
      </>
    </Router>

)
```